# Find Sub Directories in Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm looking for some regex that will only return the first three sub directories that begin and end with a "/"

i.e. directories like:
"/dir/" 
 "/dir/dir/" 
 "/dir//dir/dir/"

But I don't want to include the home page or TLD paths with no ending "/"
E.g. 
"/"
"/cart"
"/account"

This regex kind of works Regex for exactly three sub-directories
^/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/$

But it brings in the items I don't want to include.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use it as report filter in Google Analytics to find path with this pattern `/dir/`, `/dir/dir/` and `/dir/dir/dir/`:

```
^\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-@:\%\._\+~#=]+\/$|^\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-@:\%\._\+~#=]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-@:\%\._\+~#=]+\/$|^\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-@:\%\._\+~#=]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-@:\%\._\+~#=]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-@:\%\._\+~#=]+\/$
```

Comment: Hi Michele - I'm looking for all the top 3 dirs e.g. /dir/dir/dir/. Your one seems to just include the third https://regex101.com/r/jnYwGX/1

Comment: Now it works for pattern like /dir/, /dir/dir/ and /dir/dir/dir/ (try it in google analytics, test tools don't always respond in the same way as analytics)

Comment: Okay - I can see it working now. Many thanks Michele